# Create a new tab instead of a panel

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have gone through the examples of Add-on SDK 1.5 yet haven't seen anything like a web page which the addon can interact with the user and get input from him. There are only dialogs called `panel`s and I really would like to have a real page in a tab like in google-chrome addons.

Is it even possible with the Add-on SDK (1.5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can create a tab, you use [`tabs.open()`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/addon-kit/docs/tabs.html#open%28options%29). As to interacting with this tab - you probably want to [register a content script](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html) before opening the tab. Just like you would do it with Google Chrome.

Comment: pfff I have been seeking for it as `page`, `new_page` or `content` or something, thanks